# node - fs - reading two files so they can be compared

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I read two file using fs and have both result available in a way , where I can compare them. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448336/reading-and-returning-multiple-files-in-node-js-using-fs-readfile) but its slightly different and I couldnt find a way to do what I need.

I can call the `diffChars` from callback, but how to do with two callback functions?

```
  fs.readFile('/abc1.txt',  function (err, data1) {
    console.log(data1);
});
  fs.readFile('/abc1.txt',  function (err, data2) {
    console.log(data2);
});

 later I want to do like this

 var fileDiff = require("diff");
 var difference = fileDiff.diffChars(data1,data2);
 cnsole.log(difference);
```

note: I am restrictive on libraries I can use because of npm proxy repository

Comment: try `fs.readFileSync`, the "Synchronous version of `fs.readFile()`. Returns the contents of the path."

Comment: If you can: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra gives a version of `readFile` returning a promise instead of using a callback. Otherwise look at [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect case for a `Promise` and `Promise.all`.

```
function readFile(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.readFile(name,  function (err, data) {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(readFile('file1'), readFile('file2')).then(data => {
   var file1 = data[0];
   var file2 = data[1];
});
```

Comment: when I do like above plus this code `var fileDiff = require('diff'); var difference = fileDiff.diffSentences(file1, file2);` or `diffChars`  , I get 'TypeError: value.split is not a function'

Comment: so why does `console.log(typeof file1)` and `console.log(typeof file2)` returns a `string` ?

Comment: it worked after I added `.toString()` to `file1` and `file2` . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the callback functions. You could use `fs.readFileSync()`.

**EDIT** However, `fs.readFileSync()` is blocking and the next line will only be executed once the function returns.

If you insist on using callbacks:

```
fs.readFile("abc123.txt", (error1, data1) => {
  if (error1) {
    return;
  }

  fs.readFile("abc456.txt", (error2, data2) => {
    if (error2) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(data1 === data2);
  });
});
```

Comment: `readFileSync` is blocking and will block the node event loop. In other words, doing this will stop everything running until the files are read.

Comment: @JimWright which *could* be ok, depending on the context of usage. I know it's definitely not near as common as an async read though, but valid contexts exist for sure.

Comment: @JimWright, edited my answer, thanks. It does make sense to mention it.

Comment: @Moritz Schmitz v. Hülst same as my comment above on Daniel A. White answer

Answer (score 0):

Node uses asynchronous style of coding.
So when you are reading file one the 2nd file is also being read and also the next code is being executed.
Thus you can use promises or callbacks.
Here is one solution

```
fs.readFile('/abc1.txt',  function (err, data1) {
    console.log(data1);
    fs.readFile('/abc1.txt',  function (err, data2) {
        console.log(data2);
        var fileDiff = require("diff");
        var difference = fileDiff.diffChars(data1,data2);
        console.log(difference);
    });      
});
```

or use promises like

```
var data;
fs.readFile('/abc1.txt')
.then((data1)=>{
    data = data1;
    return(fs.readFile('/abc1.txt'))
})
.then((data2)=>{
    var difference = fileDiff.diffChars(data1,data2);
    return(difference)
})
/* do what ever you want here*/
.catch((err)=>{throw err;})
```