# How to read and write multiple text file in node js

Tags: node.js

In this below code I can read `file1.txt` data and write it to `file2.txt`, but I want to read *file1*, *file2*, *file3*, and *file4* and then write all those data to `file5.txt`. How to do that? Can anyone edit the below code as i am beginner

```
 var fs = require("fs");

    fs.readFile('file1.txt',function(err, data){
        fs.writeFile('file2.txt', data)
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019533/2630817 something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to do this would be to nest the multiple readFiles and then have the writeFile nested inside. Something like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('file1.txt',function(err1, data1){
    fs.readFile('file2.txt',function(err2, data2){
        fs.readFile('file3.txt',function(err3, data3){
             if(err1 || err2 || err3){
                   throw new Error();
             }
             let data = data1+data2+data3;
             fs.writeFile('file4.txt', data);
         });
    });
});
```

The other method to achieve this would be to use the [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) or a similar promise library.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);
var writeFile = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile);

var promiseArray = [readFile('file1.txt'), readFile('file2.txt'), readFile('file3.txt')];

Promise.all(promiseArray).then((dataArray)=>{
     var data = '';
     for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
          data += dataArray[i];
     }
     return writeFile('file4.txt', data);
});
```

I would suggest to use the second method. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me and another think how to create file1,file2,file3 with text in nest like this

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I found was installing the package concat -- it will do all the legwork for you :)  Please also note that  `writeFile` has been deprecated for `writeFileSync` (Code [DEP0013]).

First install the package

```
npm install concat
```

Then code

```
const concat = require('concat'); //Or use ES6 Syntax
const fs = require('fs');


concat(['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']).then(files_being_written => 
fs.writeFileSync('your-concated-file.txt', files_being_written))

// or this way
// concat(['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt'], 'your-concated-file.txt')
```

Source(s):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14770

Answer (score 0):

I will opt for the promise library for this. Making your Objects `thenable` increases code readability and prevents the code from growing in the right side. My solution will be almost same like other solution except for I am using nodejs Buffer to concatenate the data of other files.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file1 = 'a.txt'
const file2 = 'b.txt'

const allPromises = [file1, file2].map(eachFile => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(eachFile, (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err)
            }else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
})

Promise.all(allPromises).then(onfulfilled => {
    const totalBufferContent = Buffer.concat(onfulfilled)
    fs.writeFile('c.txt', totalBufferContent, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log('Done')
    })
})
```